# docker: command not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I am running Jenkins on Openshfit using Catalog, however, after creating my pipeline, I am getting Docker build failed

- docker build -t biloocabba/kncare:2 .
  /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/KnCare-prod/workspace@tmp/durable-8e36408e/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found

- I was trying to access the Pod as root and install docker from there but not possible. scc showing restricted mode.
- Any idea how to Edite the yml file to get the pod to run with root privileges

Answer (score 0):

First , you should not run pod as root user because it can compromise whole openshift cluster security .  Its not best practice to run as root user.

I would suggest using docker build config or jenkins pipeline strategy to build images in oenshift jenkins.

Still if you want to run your pod as root user , then  follow the below steps :

1. create a service account  in your namespace
2. add the service account to "anyuid" scc
3. then run your pod with this service account.

Comment: thank you for the advice, I am new with Openshift, I managed to create a new image using Buildconfig

Comment: Are you running it with anyuid now ?

Comment: I am new to Openshift world , I solved the issue by using  BuildConfig / Image stream solution to run the docker, thanks again.